# Pine Script routine to find different Pattern

Tags: pattern-matching, pine-script

I'm looking for a way to program a routine in PineScript that can, for example, recognize the pattern in the picture. One problem for me is that it should work in different symbols, regardless of whether they cost 0.345 USD or 312.68 USD. So in different values.

It is specifically about a routine that recognizes these 5 bars, for example, regardless of the resolution/value.

Thanks for your help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hp8WZ.jpg)

Comment: What is that pattern? What is happening there? For patterns, you should calculate how big the body is, how big the shadows are etc. then compare those values with other candles. What have you tried?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.